# Mapping elements of a data frame by looping through another data frame

Tags: r, comparison, dataframe

I have two R data frame with differing dimensions. However but data frames have an `id` column

**df1:**

```
nrow(df1)=22308

                     c1      c2       c3           pattern1.match
ENSMUSG00000000001_at 10.175115 10.175423 10.109524              0
ENSMUSG00000000003_at  2.133651  2.144733  2.106649              0
ENSMUSG00000000028_at  5.713781  5.714827  5.701983              0
```

**df2:**

```
                               Genes Pattern.Count
ENSMUSG00000000276 ENSMUSG00000000276_at             1
ENSMUSG00000000876 ENSMUSG00000000876_at             1
ENSMUSG00000001065 ENSMUSG00000001065_at             1
ENSMUSG00000001098 ENSMUSG00000001098_at             1

nrow(df2)=425
```

I would like to loop through `df2`, and find all genes that have `pattern.count=1` and check it in `df1$pattern1.match` column.

Basically I would like to overwrite the fields `GENES` AND  `pattern1.match` with the `df2$Genes` and `df2$Pattern.Count`. All the elements from  `df2$Pattern.Count` are equal to one.

I wrote this function, but R freezes while looping through all these rows.

```
idcol <- ncol(df1)
return.frame.matches <- function(df1, df2, idcol) { 
    for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) { 
         for (j in 1:nrow(df2))
                 if(df1[i, 1] == df2[j, 1]) { 
                     df1[i, idcol] = 1
                     break
                 }    
     }
     return (df1) 
}
```

Is there another way of doing that without almost killing the computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I get exactly what you are doing, but the following should at least get you closer.

The first column of `df1` doesn't seem to have a name, are they `rownames`?

If so,

```
df1$Genes <- rownames(df1)
```

Then you could then do a `merge` to create a new dataframe with the genes you require:

```
merge(df1,subset(df2,Pattern.Count==1))
```

Note they are matching on the common column `Genes`. I'm not sure what you want to do with the `pattern1.match` column, but a `subset` on the `df1` part of `merge` can incorporate conditions on that.

**Edit**

Going by the extra information in the comments,

```
df1$pattern1.match <- as.numeric(df1$Genes %in% df2$Genes)
```

should achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: so I df1- main data frame, and I want to check int the df1$pattern.match column which genes can be found in df2...basically the genes in df2 are included in df1, and I want to check that by marking the element of the df1$pattern.match to 1, when a gene has been found in df2

Comment: the Pattern.Count column has only elements =1, since it has already been extracted from another data set

Comment: OK, there's a better solution there now which should solve the problem.

Comment: it still dies for some reason...and as mentioned in my edited post, all the elements from df2 are eq to 1

Comment: cc<-df1[df1$pattern1.match>0]
> length(cc)  [1] 0...so it doesn't update the column, even though it makes a lot of sense..

Comment: Hmmm, well the definition of the problem has changed now since the `df2$Genes` column entries are different. Looking at the way they are formatted, you can get the df1 entries to match using `paste` and `substr`: `df1$Genes <- paste(substr(df1$Genes,1,18),df1$Genes)`

Comment: there is a huge freaking naming problem..I cannot believe I couldn't see that, I have formatted the gene column, but the rownames where not compatible..I am trying to fix that and hopefully it will work soon ...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data is not enough to play around with, but here is what I would start with:

```
dfm <- merge( df1, df2, by = idcol, all = TRUE )
dfm_pc <- subset( dfm, Pattern.Count == 1 )
```

I took the "idcol" from your code, don't see it in the data.

Comment: col=ncol(df1), since I want to update the last column of df2..like marking in df1$ pattern1.match which gene can be found in df2...